# Virtual mouse for Android

Tags: android, mouse

Sometimes I find it very difficult to click a link in Android.

I am wondering if there is any good virtual mouse app for Android users whose fingers are not slim enough to click a web link.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a virtual mouse app. Can you explain how it would work? Would pairing your phone with a bluetooth mouse suffice?

Comment: Hi Huey. The virtual mouse is that when you use your finger to touch the cell phone's screen, a mouse will appear like you have a real USB mouse.

Comment: Hi Huey, could you explain it in detail as an answer so that I can give you a vote up and accept it? Please help.